# LibGDX Multiple Fullscreen Windows

Tags: java, libgdx, fullscreen, monitors

I am writing a program to display text on two monitors.

Right now my method is to launch a LibGDX window on both monitors, then control each separately.
However, when both are in fullscreen, only one window can have focus. The out-of-focus window gets hidden. How do I solve this?

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Java 1.8
- LibGDX 1.9.3, using LWJGL 3 backend

Code:

- In the ApplicationListener:

  ```
  @Override
  public void show() throws RuntimeException {
     // Throws exception if it is set to go to monitor 1 and it does not exist

     if (external && Gdx.graphics.getMonitors().length < 2)
          throw new RuntimeException("Cannot extend to secondary monitor.");

      Gdx.graphics.setFullscreenMode(Gdx.graphics.getDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getMonitors()[external ? 1 : 0]));
  }
  ```
- Then, to open the window:

  ```
  @Override
  public void openWindow(ApplicationListener a) {
     Lwjgl3WindowConfiguration config = new Lwjgl3WindowConfiguration();

     config.setTitle(title);

     config.setWindowListener(new Lwjgl3WindowListener() {

         @Override
         public void iconified() {}

         @Override
         public void focusLost() {}

         @Override
         public void focusGained() {}

         @Override
         public void filesDropped(String[] files) {}

         @Override
         public void deiconified() {}

         @Override
         public boolean closeRequested() { 
             return true;
         }
     });

     Lwjgl3Application app = (Lwjgl3Application) Gdx.app;
     window = app.newWindow(a, config);
     DesktopLauncher.openWindows.add(window);  // Used to close all windows later
  }
  ```

Am I looking at this the wrong way?
Thanks!

Comment: I can only really see problems with two fullscreen windows. Only one window can have focus at a time, fullscreen or not. I would recommend using a single fullscreen window with twice the width and manage the window with two virtual screens. This would eleminate the focus problem and save you from a million other problems.

Comment: @IronMonkey Thanks. I'll try that.